# format of goodness of fit table in binomial regression in r

Tags: r, datatable, format, logistic-regression

I tried doing a goodness of fit test for binomial regression that I did and get this results:
[goodness of fit result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31vGS.png)

in the example my teacher gave the table was
row = 0   1
column =0  1

while mine is
column = 1   0
row =  0  1
as seen in the image above

does this difference matter in the results I get?

Answer (score 0):

The results won't change. But if you like you can change the order of the columns using

> table()[,2:1]